# How to escape filename containing single and double quotes mix?

Tags: linux, bash, escape

Let's say i create a filename with this:

```
xb@dnxb:/tmp/test$ touch '"i'"'"'m noob.mp4"'
xb@dnxb:/tmp/test$ ls -1
"i'm noob.mp4"
xb@dnxb:/tmp/test$
```

Then `vim .` to go inside Netrw directory listing.

```
" ============================================================================
" Netrw Directory Listing                                        (netrw v156)
"   /tmp/test
"   Sorted by      name
"   Sort sequence: [\/]$,\<core\%(\.\d\+\)\=\>,\.h$,\.c$,\.cpp$,\~\=\*$,*,\.o$,\.obj$,\.info$,\.swp$,\.bak$,\~$
"   Quick Help: <F1>:help  -:go up dir  D:delete  R:rename  s:sort-by  x:special
" ==============================================================================
../
./
"i'm noob.mp4"
```

Then press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to view the file. Type:

```
:!ls -l %
```

It will shows error:

```
xb@dnxb:/tmp/test$ vim .

ls: cannot access '/tmp/test/i'\''m noob.mp4': No such file or directory

shell returned 2

Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

I also tried:

[1] `:!ls -l '%'`:

```
Press ENTER or type command to continue
/bin/bash: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
/bin/bash: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file

shell returned 1

Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

[2] `:!ls -l "%"`:

```
Press ENTER or type command to continue
/bin/bash: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
/bin/bash: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file

shell returned 1

Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

[3] `:!ls -l expand("%")`:

```
/bin/bash: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/bin/bash: -c: line 0: `ls -l expand(""i'm noob.mp4"")'

shell returned 1

Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

[4] `!ls -l shellescape("%")`:

```
/bin/bash: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/bin/bash: -c: line 0: `ls -l shellescape("/tmp/test/"i'm noob.mp4"")'

shell returned 1

Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

[5] `!ls -l shellescape(expand("%"))`:

```
/bin/bash: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/bin/bash: -c: line 0: `ls -l shellescape(expand("/tmp/test/"i'm noob.mp4""))'

shell returned 1

Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

My ultimate goal is perform `rsync` by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>, e.g:

```
nnoremap <C-c> :!eval `ssh-agent -s`; ssh-add; rsync -azvb --no-t % xiaobai@127.0.0.1:/home/xiaobai/storage/
```

My platform is Kali Linux's `vim.gtk3`, bash. Fedora's `vim` and `gvim` also have the same problem.

What's the correct syntax to escape filename containing single and double quotes ?

Comment: Hmmm. How about `exec '!ls -l' shellescape(expand('%'))`?

Comment: @muru Thanks, it did work ! But still i need to figure out why `rsync` syntax not working. Can you provide a key mapping answer based on `rsync` above as answer ? I think i might need to add single quote to destination but failed. e.g. ```nnoremap <C-c> :exec '!eval `ssh-agent -s`; ssh-add; rsync -azvb --no-t' shellescape(expand('%')) 'xiaobai@127.0.0.1:/tmp/'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the answer from [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/319449/64403), backslash-escape literally every character:

```
nnoremap <C-c> :!eval `ssh-agent -s`; ssh-add; rsync -azvb --no-t %:gs/./\\&/:p 'xiaobai@127.0.0.1:/tmp/'
```

Tested with chinese unicode characters and works fine, even in virtual console.

But I  still welcome any alternative answers or more detailed explanation. Thanks.